# Symfony maintaining relative path for file uploads

Tags: php, symfony

I'm using Symfony 4.1, and I had a hard time getting the relative/fullpath to work as I want it.

In my database, I have a Customer entity with an attribute called photo.

```
<?php
namespace App\Entity;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Entity\CustomerRepository")
 * @ORM\Table("Customer")
 */
class Customer {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

     /**
       * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
       *
       * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "image/png","image/jpeg" })
       */
     private $photo;

     public function getPhoto(): ?string
     {
        return $this->photo;
     }

     public function setPhoto(?string $photo): self
     {
        $this->photo = $photo;
        return $this;
     }
```

This makes sense and when I save the Customer with a Photo upload, it saves the photo in the database and on the filesystem as I expect.

In the database, the photo column will be set to something like '010925c8c427bddca9020197212b64af.png'

That's what I want, so it's all good.

The problem came up when I was trying to update an existing Customer entity. Customer->getPhoto() will return the relative path file name '010925c8c427bddca9020197212b64af.png.'

But the form doesn't pass validation, it says that this file doesn't exist.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$custRepo = $em->getRepository('App:Customer');
$customer = $custRepo->findOneById($id);
$custForm = $this->createForm(CustomerType::class, $customer);
$custForm->handleRequest($request);
if ($custForm->isSubmitted() && $custForm->isValid()) {
    $em->flush();
}
```

It fails because the validation doesn't look in the photos directory.

Here's my solution, which does work, but it seems too hackish. I wasn't wondering if someone had a more elegant approach to this.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$custRepo = $em->getRepository('App:Customer');
$customer = $custRepo->findOneById($id);
$customer->setPhoto(new File($this->getParameter('photos_dir') .'/' . $customer->getPhoto()));
$custForm = $this->createForm(CustomerType::class, $customer);
$custForm->handleRequest($request);
if ($custForm->isSubmitted() && $custForm->isValid()) {
    $photoPathParts = explode('/', $customer->getPhoto());
    $customer->setPhoto(array_pop($photoPathParts));
    $em->flush();
}
```

I'm getting the fullpath for the photo and updating the entity I'm currently work on. That gets the form validation to pass, but if I just save it, the path in the db is updated with the full path to the photo. That's not what I want, so I reset the photo to the relative path filename.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
 *
 * @Assert\File(mimeTypes={ "image/png","image/jpeg" })
 */
 private $photo;
```

Comment: Take a look here at the end: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/upload_file.html
You can create a Doctrine listener which will modify `$photo` property as you want. You can create a `File` instance, like you do right now in controller, or just change its value to have full path instead of just the filename.

Comment: you do not have to edit the photo each time you update the customer. If you want to change the photo so you should upload new one and remove the oldest, else do not fill the input file field.

Comment: @hous, the form doesn't have the photo in it. It's getting the form data with $custRepo->findOneById($id); Maybe that's the issue, getting the customer from the db.

Comment: show me how you do validate the form, I mean you have some Assert for example in the entity ?

Comment: I updated the question. I've done this a bunch of times before, I don't know why I'm struggling with it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this example how to upload image. The image is in a separate entity , you can relate it to customer OneToOne.

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity;

/**
 * Image
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="image")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\ImageRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Image
{
/**
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="extension", type="string", length=180)
 */

private $name;
/**
 * @Assert\Image()
 */
public $file;

private $tempFilename;

public function getId(): ?int
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getName(): ?string
{
    return $this->name;
}

public function setName(string $name): self
{
    $this->name = $name;
    return $this;
}

public function setFile(UploadedFile $file)
{
    $this->file = $file;
    if (null !== $this->extension) {
        $this->tempFilename = $this->name;
        $this->extension = null;
        $this->name = null;
    }
}

public function getFile()
{
    return $this->file;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist()
 * @ORM\PreUpdate()
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }
    $extension = $this->file->guessExtension();
    $this->name = md5(uniqid('', true)) . '.' . $extension;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist()
 * @ORM\PostUpdate()
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }
    if (null !== $this->tempFilename) {
        $oldFile = $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->tempFilename;
        if (file_exists($oldFile)) {
            unlink($oldFile);
        }
    }
    $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->name);
}

/**
 * @ORM\PreRemove()
 */
public function preRemoveUpload()
{
    $this->tempFilename = $this->getUploadRootDir() . '/' . $this->name;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove()
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    if (file_exists($this->tempFilename)) {
        unlink($this->tempFilename);
    }
}

//folder
public function getUploadDir()
{
    return 'uploads/photos';
}

// path to folder web
protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__ . '/../../public/' . $this->getUploadDir();
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return $this->getUploadDir() . '/' . $this->getName();
}

}
```

ImageFormType

**NB:** You should use the public **attribue $file** in the formType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('file', FileType::class, array(
            'label'=> false,
        ))
    ;
}
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you. That looks more familiar. I've been on medication for the last few days and my mental capacity is diminished. Thanks helping out.

Comment: Hope that help you. In the controller do not add any thing extra for the image, just test if $form is valid and than do persist and flush.

Comment: Yes, that part where I was messing with it in the controller seemed wrong.

Comment: if everything is fine you can show image using the webPath function like this <img src="{{ asset( customer.image.webPath) }}">